# How do you resolve this python tkinter error?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk

class Calculator(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master.geometry("300x800")
        self.master.title("GUI Calculator")
        self.pack()

    # CREATE BUTTONS IN A FOR LOOP.
    btnclrs = ["Blue", "Red", "Green", "Red", "Green", "Blue", "Red", "Green", 
"Blue"]
    self.btns = []
    for i in range(9):
        def callback(self=self, var=i+1):
            self.text.insert(tk.END, var)
            self.text.pack()
        button = tk.Button(text=i+1, fg=btnclrs[i], bg="Black", command=callback)
        button.pack()
        self.btns.append(button)

    self.text = tk.Text(self.master)
    self.text.bind("<Key-Return>", self.calculation)  # DON'T CALL FUNCTION WHEN BINDING.
    self.text.pack()
    self.text.focus_set()  # ADDED SO BOUND EVENT-HANDLERS WILL BE CALLED.


    operations = ["+", "-", "*", "/"]
    self.ops = []

    for i in range(4):
        def callback1(self=self, var=operations[i]):
            self.text.insert(tk.END, var)
            self.text.pack()
        buttono = tk.Button(text=operations[i], fg="Black", bg="Black", command=callback1)
        buttono.pack()
        self.ops.append(buttono)

    self.output = tk.Text(self.master)
    self.output.insert(1.0, "Output: \n")
    self.output.pack()
    self.master.mainloop()


def calculation(self, event = None):
    out = self.text.get('1.0', 'end')
    output1 = eval(out)
    self.output.delete(1.0, tk.END)
    self.output.insert(1.0, output1)

calc_button = tk.Button(text = "Calculate", fg = "Blue", bg = "White", command = calculation)
calc_button.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Calculator()
```

I have finished coding all the logic for this calculator and I just want to create a "Calculate" viewable button for the user to press. It is resulting in the following error:

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/**init**.py", line 1883, in **call**
return self.func(*args)
TypeError: calculation() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Why is this happening?

Comment: Delete the "self" argument from `calculation`.

Comment: Your code failed to run.  Fix the indentation issue of your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a function outside of the class, it shouldn't take a `self` argument. However, your implementation of `calculation` requires `self`, so you need to define the method inside the class.

```
class Calculator(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        ...
    def calculation(self, event = None)
        ...
```

Next, you need to call `calculation` from an instance of `Calculator`. To do that, you must create the instance before you create the button that uses the instance:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    calc = Calculator()
    calc_button = tk.Button(..., command = calc.calculation)
    calc_button.pack()
```

Also, as a best practice you should *not* call `self.pack` inside of `Calculation`. A geometry manager (`pack`, `place`, `grid`) should normally be called in the same context that the widget was created.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    calc = Calculator()
    calc_button = tk.Button(..., command = calc.calculation)
    calc.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    calc_button.pack(side="bottom")
```